# Using SDL2 RenderDraw functions with Emscripten

Tags: sdl, emscripten

I've been struggling to port a simple C program that uses SDL2 for graphics to the web using emscripten. I scanned through example programs but was unable to find one that draws to the screen using SDL_RenderDrawPoint, SDL_RenderDrawLine, or SDL_RenderDrawRect. These functions work on the windows/ubuntu versions of my program, but not on the emscripten version. I simply see the screen painted with the cleared color, but nothing drawn to it.

Here's sample code that showcases the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <assert.h>
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // setup
    SDL_Window * window;
    SDL_Renderer * renderer;
    assert(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 320, 0, &window, &renderer);

    // clear screen with red color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 200, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    // draw green line across screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, 0, 640, 320);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    // free resources
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I saved this code to main.c then ran:

`emcc main.c -s USE_SDL=2 -o a.html`

On Windows/Ubuntu, I see this:
[image]

On Emscripten (Chrome) I see this:
[image]

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With emscripten you almost always have to use its main loop approach. Using `SDL_Delay` or any other form of sleeping is bad because it works differently from ordinary PC targets (more like spinlock than sleep). You should use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <assert.h>
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

SDL_Window * window;
SDL_Renderer * renderer;

void render_func(void) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 200, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, 0, 640, 320);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
    emscripten_cancel_main_loop();
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 320, 0, &window, &renderer);

#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
    emscripten_set_main_loop(render_func, 60, 1);
#else
    render_func();
#endif

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot. You pin-pointed the issue in the dummy snippet. After looking at your code, I realized the last parameter you passed to emscripten_set_main_loop was 1. In my real program I used emscripten_set_main_loop, but passed 0 as the last parameter. Nothing was printed to the screen. After making the change, it works as intended. I read the description of the last parameter [here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.emscripten_set_main_loop) but I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: Did the post-`emscripten_set_main_loop()` cleanup code actually get executed with 2015-era Emscripten?